# change variable value with axios, useeffect, and usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, use-effect

i'm newbie here, i'm stuck. i want to change value from false to true, to stop shimmering when data sucessfully to load.

i have action like this

```
import axios from "axios";
import { CONSTANT_LINK } from "./constants";
import { GET } from "./constants";
import { ERROR } from "./constants";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export const addData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get(CONSTANT_LINK)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(addDataSuccess(res.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(errorData(true));
        console.log("error");
      });
  };
};

const addDataSuccess = (todo) => ({
  type: GET,
  payload: todo,
});

const errorData = (error) => ({
  type: ERROR,
  payload: error,
});
```

and this is my homepage which influential in this matter

```
const [shimmerValue, setShimmerValue] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => { 
    setShimmerValue(true)
    dispatch(addData());
  }, []);
 <ShimmerPlaceholder visible={shimmerValue} height={20}>
            <Text style={styles.welcomeName}>Welcome,Barret</Text>
          </ShimmerPlaceholder>
```

i dont understand how it works

Comment: If ShimmerPlaceholder is component which you want to use it everywhere , then you shouldnt bind its value to state of one component, in the other hand its value  should be in your redux state and in every conponent then you access it , use useSelector and it could be accessible every where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass callback like this

```
const [shimmerValue, setShimmerValue] = useState(false);

const updateShimmerValue = () => {
  setShimmerValue(true);
}
useEffect(() => { 
    // setShimmerValue(true) // remove this from here
    dispatch(addData(updateShimmerValue)); // pass callback as param here
  }, []);
```

Callback call here like

```
export const addData = (callback) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get(CONSTANT_LINK)
      .then((res) => {
        ....
        callback(); // trigger callback like this here
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        ....
      });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use it:

```
const [shimmerValue, setShimmerValue] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
    setState(state => ({ ...state, shimmerValue: true }));
    dispatch(addData());
}, [shimmerValue]);
```